# R readLines() ignores url tags followed by #

Tags: r, web-scraping

when I use
    readLines("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=AGAP8#see-all")
I get a vector identical to
    readLines("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=AGAP8")
which is an entirely different page from what I get when I go to the URL in browser. Is there a way to retrieve the HTML from the page with the extra data of the #see-all?

the #see-all version of the page forces it to be the search results page (in browser), rather than 'helpful' (annoying) redirects to the wrong page.

Comment: That part is not actually sent to the server at all.  It sounds like you actually want a headless browser to run Javascript.

Comment: any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: When I click on your links,  I get exactly the same pages.

Comment: I do too, probably some sort of cookie-JS interaction, when I first went to the shorter link, I got the page on AGAP4, which is the page that I get the HTML for when I use readLines().